# How to guarantee execution order with Node's stream writer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, streamwriter

How can I change this code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

let list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
list.forEach(x => {
  console.log('processing ' + x);
  let out_path = x + '.txt';
  let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(out_path);
  writeStream.write('a lot of stuff will go here', 'utf8');
  writeStream.on('finish', () => {
    console.log(out_path + ' saved');
  });
  writeStream.end();
});
```

to get this:

```
processing a
a.txt saved
processing b
b.txt saved
processing c
c.txt saved
```

instead of this:

```
processing a
processing b
processing c
a.txt saved
b.txt saved
c.txt saved
```

?

It works fine if I were building an object in the `forEach` loop and then writing each object to file using `fs.writeFile`... but I can't do that, because I'm writing huge amounts of data (GBs) and would soon reach the heap's limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use async await

```
(async () => {
  const fs = require('fs');

  let list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  for (let x of list) {
    console.log('processing ' + x);
    let out_path = x + '.txt';
    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(out_path);
    writeStream.write('a lot of stuff will go here', 'utf8');
    writeStream.end();
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      writeStream.on('finish', () => {
        console.log(out_path + ' saved');
        resolve();
      });
    })  
  }
})();
```

Comment: `writeStream.end();` does need to be above the Promise =) Then everything works! Thanks!!